# Problem with controls in MDI form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi, mdichild

I have placed a button on MDI form , now when I open a child form , the button remains on top and distracts the child form , is there a way to solve it?
I have done following to send the button back when any child is activated.But I am wondering to call button1.BringToFront();

```
private void MDIParent1_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.SendToBack();
}
```

I tried following but it doesnt work.

```
private void MDIParent1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BringToFront();
}
```

I think its a lasting bug of .net , there are many posts trying to solve it , using dock with a panel etc , but docking just for a button makes the application work space less.

Comment: So basically senttoback is working but bringtofront isn't, is it?

Comment: @ siddharth, no bringtofront is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question ! here is how I implemented it , the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699098/mdiparent-click/3700425#3700425) was what I was missing.

```
public MDIParent1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (var ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl is MdiClient)
                {
                    (ctl as MdiClient).GotFocus  += Client_gotfocus;
                    (ctl as MdiClient).LostFocus  += Client_lostfocus;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        private void Client_gotfocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.BringToFront();
        }
        private void Client_lostfocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.SendToBack ();
        }
```