# mdiparent click

Tags: .net, winforms, mdi, mdiparent

The click ,double click on mdi parent of the .net MDI form does not work is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's not much to go on without knowing exactly what you click on.  The gray background of the parent is a separate control, an MdiClient, not the form.  You'd register a click event for it with code like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var ctl in this.Controls) {
            if (ctl is MdiClient) {
                (ctl as MdiClient).Click += Client_Click;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void Client_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // etc...
    }
```

Comment: Great answer Thanks, but quite surprising that I could not find it any where else,It also solves by another question as listed in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698445/problem-with-controls-in-mdi-form/3706206#3706206